# How to build vp8 for armv6 on windows

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, vp8, libvpx

I'm trying to build vp8 for android armv6 but with no luck
I tried to set --target=armv6-android-gcc but i get Unrecognized toolchain 'armv6-android-gcc' error
but --target=armv7-android-gcc works just fine.
how should i do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ARM6 Android ABI in the NDK. ARM6 Android devices use the ARM5 ABI (which is the plain androideabi).